# Trying to set a flag while processing a group of rows in T-SQL / SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| MEMID | DOS_FROM | FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AMI14286568201 | 2022-01-06 | N |
| AMI14286568201 | 2022-01-06 | N |
| AMI14286568201 | 2022-01-06 | N |
| AMI14286568201 | 2022-01-06 | Y |
| AMI14286568201 | 2022-01-06 | N |
| AMI14286568201 | 2022-01-06 | N |

The MEMID will change throughout the file as I'm grouping by MEMID on a SELECT DISTINCT, so am processing this by each MEMID.

What I need to do is, for each MEMID, if the flag is Y for **ANY** row, write the MEMID, DOS_FROM, FLAG, etc. from the row with the 'Y' flag into a new table. There would be only one row in the new table (fro each MEMID) that would look like:

| MEMID | DOS_FROM | FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AMI14286568201 | 2022-01-06 | Y |

If there is no 'Y' flag for that group, then I would put an 'N' in the flag in the new table:

| MEMID | DOS_FROM | FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AMI14286568201 | 2022-01-06 | N |

What I'm not getting is how to process these by each MEMID. I'm thinking that I need to use a window function or CTE but still relatively new to using those. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I looked into using cursors for this but seems like there would be a better solution and I've just not the experience for it yet!

Comment: check out row_number(), you can use it to prioritize rows based on some values, ie. first take Y flag partitioned by memid and then N

Comment: What happens if there are multiple rows with Y? What happens if there are rows with different `DOS_FROM` values? It looks like you just want `INSERT NewTable (ColumnsHere) SELECT MEMID, MAX(DOS_FROM), MAX(FLAG) FROM YourTable GROUP BY MEMID;`

Comment: @Charlieface I'll try that. I think I'm complicating it too much in me own brain. :)

Comment: max would work, unless your dates aren't all the same per memid

Comment: Use SELECT INTO.  INSERT into YesTable (memid, dos_from, flag)
   SELECT Distinct MEMID, DOS_FROM, FLAG FROM Table1 where Flag = 'Y';

INSERT into NoTable (memid, dos_from, flag) 
   SELECT Distinct MEMID, DOS_FROM, FLAG FROM Table1, where Flag = 'N'

Answer (score 0):

Your exact intention is not quite clear, especially in regards the `DOS_FROM` column, but looks like you just need

```sql
INSERT NewTable
  (MEMID, DOS_FROM, FLAG)
SELECT MEMID, MAX(DOS_FROM), MAX(FLAG)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY MEMID;
```